# Calling a virtual function of in-memory object

Tags: c++, class, pointers, virtual

I'm trying to make an inline **constructor** for a class, which has a *virtual function*.
For the overall purpose, the function has to be virtual because `Shape::print` will be called by another Class, not knowing what kind (exact type) of Shape it is addressing.

I see that this has to be some kind of memory relevant issue. How can I call this function when using my Class-Object not constructed but as a pointer? Or am I missing something else?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual void print(){};
};

class Circle : Shape {
private:
    int r;
public:
    Circle(int radius){
        this->r = radius;
    }

    // My "inline-constructor"
    static Circle* make(int radius){
        Circle* circ = (Circle*) malloc(sizeof(Circle));
        circ->r = radius;
        return circ;
    };

    virtual void print(){
        printf("%u", this->r);
    };
};

int main(){
    Circle circObj(5);
    circObj.print(); // Works fine    
    Circle* circPtr = Circle::make(10);
    circPtr->print(); // Crashes    
    return 0;
 }
```

Thanks in advance, any help is apreciated.

Comment: A better name for "inline constructor" would be "factory function"

Comment: If I'd call something like `(new Circle(10))->print();`, wouldn't the object be removed from the memory afterwards?

Comment: Also, after each `malloc` should come a call to `free` and after each `new` should come a call for `delete` to avoid memory leak. Or use smart pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// My "inline-constructor"
static Circle* make(int radius){
    Circle* circ = (Circle*) malloc(sizeof(Circle));
    circ->r = radius;
    return circ;
};
```

This isn't any kind of a constructor. It is just a wrongly written factory method. It should just consist of

```
return new Circle(radius);
```

which makes it so trivial as to be completely pointless.

> How can I call this function when using my Class-Object not constructed but as a pointer?

```
Shape* shape = ....; // for example, new Circle(...)
shape->print();
```

No rocket science

Answer (score 3):

In you "inline-constructor", you are just allocating memory, not initializing it. For example, the vtable is not initialized, leading to a crash since `print` is virtual and its address is expected in the vtable.

Try `Circle* circ = new Circle(radius);` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `malloc` just allocates enough *raw* memory and returns it. `malloc` does not initialize the created memory. So members of your object have to be initialized manually before use. You are doing it only for the `r`, but not for the member method `print`.

You should use `new` instead of `malloc`. `new` works in two steps

1. Allocate enough memory using *operator new* ( equivalent task of `malloc`)
2. Call constructor of the object to initialize it, which actually sets values for the member.

Comment: Thanks, going to memorize this for myself ;-)